# lan intranet only Ubuntu 18.04.4 - wordpress under apache2 is not available to android or IOS but is completely available from WIN10 client

Tags: ubuntu, dns, android, lan

I have recently installed Apache2 on a stable installation of Ubuntu server 18.04.4  and completely installed a working version of wordpress which is working for internal development work.

I can't seem to access it from Android 9 or IOS. On Android, I tried the private DNS 1.1.1.1 with no change. I would think the phones and tablets should be able to see a locally resolved address.

All other server functions are working correctly: Samba etc.

Using http://ipaddress/wordpress/  works on the WIN10 PC browser but not on the Android.

/etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       myname
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

/etc/hostname
myname

enp2s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::96de:80ff:fe38:25c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 94:de:80:38:25:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 763915  bytes 288733147 (288.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 63  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 743056  bytes 796747239 (796.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 1  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 539  bytes 35424 (35.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 539  bytes 35424 (35.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

How would I get Android to browse the intranet (Lan)?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding information like which error are you getting on mobile phones (timeout? not found?), apache logs may be useful (they're under `/var/log/apache2` on ubuntu). I suspect you actually are on different networks when on mobile and on the server/PC, assuming you've entered the correct addresses everytime.
Also the IP information from the server is actually only useful if you provide the same information from all devices. If a device is on a 192.168.0.X network and others on 192.168.2.X network, they're likely not on the same LAN, so addressing with the IP may not work as you expect.

Comment: Good comment but all LAN addresses were good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the problem finally. I compared the ports used by some IP Cameras with the server. Since the cameras would allow access from Androids etc.

In short, I found another installation guide site that addresses a Virtual Host with port :443 
I re-installed Wordpress and All is Good.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wordpress-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04/